# audio input latency

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-audio

i am reading the buffer data from the iphone audio input.
i have a latency and i cant go under the resolution of 50ms changes .

here is my class which i call to get buffer audio data- i need to know how to set the latency to be lower ,  is it possible by changing the buffer size somehow, **or** i need the remoteIO
to do that . 
thanks a lot :

```
#import "SoundSensor.h"

@interface SoundSensor (Private)

- (void)updateLevels;
- (void)setupQueue;
- (void)setupFormat;
- (void)setupBuffers;
- (void)setupMetering;

@end


static SoundSensor *sharedListener = nil;

static void listeningCallback(void *inUserData, AudioQueueRef inAQ, AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer, const AudioTimeStamp *inStartTime, UInt32 inNumberPacketsDescriptions, const AudioStreamPacketDescription *inPacketDescs)
{
    NSLog(@"listeningCallback "); 
    SoundSensor *listener = (SoundSensor *)inUserData;
    if ([listener isListening])
        AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(inAQ, inBuffer, 0, NULL);

}

@implementation SoundSensor





+ (SoundSensor *)sharedListener {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedListener == nil)
            [[self alloc] init];
    }
    NSLog(@"sharedListener ");
    return sharedListener;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [sharedListener stop];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Listening






- (void)listen {
    NSLog(@"listen");
    if (queue == nil)
        [self setupQueue];
    AudioQueueStart(queue, NULL);
}

- (void)pause {
    NSLog(@"pause  ");
    if (![self isListening])

        return;

    AudioQueueStop(queue, true);
}

- (void)stop {
    NSLog(@"stop  ");
    if (queue == nil)
        return;

    AudioQueueDispose(queue, true);
    queue = nil;
}

- (BOOL)isListening {
    if (queue == nil)
        return NO;

    UInt32 isListening, ioDataSize = sizeof(UInt32);
    OSStatus result = AudioQueueGetProperty(queue, kAudioQueueProperty_IsRunning, &isListening, &ioDataSize);
    return (result != noErr) ? NO : isListening;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Levels getters

- (Float32)averagePower {   
    if (![self isListening])
        return 0.0;
    float tmp = [self levels][0].mAveragePower;
    tmp = tmp * 100;    
    return tmp;
}

- (Float32)peakPower {
    if (![self isListening])
        return 0.0;

    return [self levels][0].mPeakPower;
}

- (AudioQueueLevelMeterState *)levels {
    if (![self isListening])
        return nil;

    [self updateLevels];
    return levels;
}

- (void)updateLevels {
    UInt32 ioDataSize = format.mChannelsPerFrame * sizeof(AudioQueueLevelMeterState);
    AudioQueueGetProperty(queue, (AudioQueuePropertyID)kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentLevelMeter, levels, &ioDataSize);
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Setup

- (void)setupQueue {
    NSLog(@"setupQueue");
    if (queue)
        return;

    [self setupFormat];
    [self setupBuffers];
    AudioQueueNewInput(&format, listeningCallback, self, NULL, NULL, 0, &queue);
    [self setupMetering];   
}

- (void)setupFormat {
    NSLog(@"setupFormat ");
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    format.mSampleRate = 44100.0;
#else
    UInt32 ioDataSize = sizeof(sampleRate);
    AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareSampleRate, &ioDataSize, &sampleRate);
    format.mSampleRate = sampleRate;
#endif
    format.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    format.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
    format.mFramesPerPacket = format.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
    format.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
    format.mBytesPerPacket = format.mBytesPerFrame = 2;
}

- (void)setupBuffers {
    NSLog(@"setupBuffers ");
    AudioQueueBufferRef buffers[3];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 3; ++i) { 
        AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(queue, 735, &buffers[i]); 
        AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(queue, buffers[i], 0, NULL); 
    }
}

- (void)setupMetering {
    NSLog(@"setupMetering");
    levels = (AudioQueueLevelMeterState *)calloc(sizeof(AudioQueueLevelMeterState), format.mChannelsPerFrame);
    UInt32 trueValue = true;
    AudioQueueSetProperty(queue, kAudioQueueProperty_EnableLevelMetering, &trueValue, sizeof(UInt32));
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Singleton Pattern

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    NSLog(@"allocWithZone");
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedListener == nil) {
            sharedListener = [super allocWithZone:zone];
            return sharedListener;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    NSLog(@"copyWithZone");
    return self;
}

- (id)init {
    if ([super init] == nil)
        return nil;

    return self;
}

- (id)retain {
    return self;
}

- (unsigned)retainCount {
    return UINT_MAX;
}

- (void)release {
    // Do nothing.
}

- (id)autorelease {
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Your `setupBuffers` method is broken;  it is passing a reference to a stack allocated buffer to system API for use later...

Answer (score 0):

Using RemoteIO Audio Unit for recording, in conjunction with setting an appropriate small value (try 5.8 milliseconds) for the kAudioSessionProperty_PreferredHardwareIOBufferDuration audio session property, seems to provide a much lower latency than using the Audio Queue API for recording.  When using the RemoteIO Audio Unit for input, you will have to compute your own level metering values from raw PCM samples using some form of DSP envelope tracking code, perhaps even spectrally weighted.  There are no built-in APIs to directly provide that for RemoteIO.

Using kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentLevelMeter does not seem to be designed or configurable for low latency.